# How to return xpath union of nodes in separate trees?

Tags: xpath

It's a basic question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

```
<a>
    <b1>
        <d1>D1</d1>
        <e1>E1</e1>
    </b1>
    <b2>
        <c2>
            <d2>D2</d2>
            <e2>E2</e2>
        </c2>
    </b2>
</a>
```

From the above I'd like to return:

```
<a>    
    <d1>D1</d1>
    <e1>E1</e1>
    <d2>D2</d2>
    <e2>E2</e2>
</a>
```

And not:

```
<a>
    <b1>
        <d1>D1</d1>
        <e1>E1</e1>
    </b1>
    <b2>
        <d2>D2</d2>
        <e2>E2</e2>
    </b2>
</a>
```

If that makes any sense. I tried "/a", but that gave me:

```
<a>
    <b1>
        <d1>D1</d1>
        <e1>E1</e1>
    </b1>
    <b2>
        <c2>D2E2</c2>
    </b2>
</a>
```

Comment: What you're asking to perform is a transformation of the node tree. That's not what XPath is for, but it is exactly what XSLT is for. XQuery is another way to do it. Now if you're not familiar with how to apply an XSL transformation or an XQuery, we can tell you that but we'll need to know the "host" language where you've been applying XPath. JavaScript? Perl? Python? C++?

Answer (score 3):

If you meant to select all leave nodes (nodes without child node(s)), you can try this XPath :

```
//*[not(*)]
```

Or using XPath union (`|`) to get child nodes of `<b1>` and `<c2>` :

```
(//b1/* | //c2/*)
```

Given sample XML you posted, both XPath above will return :

```
<d1>D1</d1>
<e1>E1</e1>
<d2>D2</d2>
<e2>E2</e2>
```

But if you really need the result to be wrapped in `<a>`, then I agree with @minopret comment, that isn't what XPath meant to do. XSLT is more proper way to transform an XML to different format.

**UPDATE :**

In respond to your last comment, there is no such grouping in XPath. Should be done in the host language if you need that data structure. Your best bet is to select parent of those desired nodes in XPath so you get them *grouped* by their parent. Then you can do further processing in the host language, for example :

```
//*[not(*)]/parent::*
//*[*[not(*)]]
```

Any of above two XPath queries can return :

```
<b1>
    <d1>D1</d1>
    <e1>E1</e1>
</b1>
<c2>
    <d2>D2</d2>
    <e2>E2</e2>
</c2>
```

Comment: Thanks, @har07. Don't really need the wrapping. Just letting off my ignorance of xpath syntax. Thanks again.

Comment: @AndréLevy no problem. I updated my answer with another possible XPath using union, maybe more suitable according to the question title..

Comment: Spoke too soon. Didn't work, @har07. What I need is {{D11,E11,D21,E21},{D12,E12,D22,E22},...}, and I'm getting a flattened set: {D11,E11,D21,E21,D12,E12,D22,E22,...}, if that makes any sense.

Comment: That doesn't makes sense in *XPath only* point of view, updated my answer with the closest thing XPath can give you.

Comment: Yeah, neither of those worked. Still the closest I have is /*/*, but that still gives me {{D11,E11,D21E21},{D12,E12,D22E22},...} (sorry about the notation; I'm doing this in Google Sheets, and am aiming for a matrix).

Answer (score 3):

XPath can only return nodes that are already present in your source tree. To construct new nodes, or reorganise the tree, you need XSLT or XQuery.